# How can I efficiently ArrayFlatten a matrix of sparse matrices?

Tags: sparse-arrays

I have a matrix of sparse matrices that I want to convert to a sparse block matrix. So, basically I want what `ArrayFlatten` does, except that I want the output to be sparse. So e.g.:

```
sp = SparseArray[{{2, 2} -> 1.}, {50, 50}];
sparseArrayFlatten[
 {
  {sp, 0},
  {0, -sp}
  }]
```

should return `SparseArray[{{2, 2} -> 1., {52, 52} -> -1., {_, _} -> 0},{100,100}]`.

Currently, I use `SparseArray@ArrayFlatten[...]`, but for large matrices, this is inefficient.

(Sometimes `ArrayFlatten` *does* return a sparse array, but I haven't completely figured out when. For example, if I remove the `-` sign above, or if I use `-> 1` instead of `-> 1.`, I get a sparse result.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Everything needs to be of the same precision including the background element.

Then this:

```
sp = SparseArray[{{2, 2} -> 1.}, {50, 50}, 0.];
ArrayFlatten[{{sp, 0.}, {0., -sp}}]
```

will return a `SparseArray` without creating a dense matrix first.

Comment: @ThunderBiggi, done.